# Nested list (of strings) to matrix of float in python

Tags: list, numpy

I wondered  what would convert a large list, structured like `['12,-1', '0.01,3']`  to an array like

```
12    -1  
0.01   3
```

The following code does this, but I don't think it is efficient:

```
import numpy as nu  
list1 = ['12,-1', '0.01,3']  
pp=  nu.zeros(shape=(len (list1),2))  
for i in range (len (list1)):  
   pp[i,0]= map (float,list1[i].split(','))[0]  
   pp[i,1]= map (float,list1[i].split(','))[1]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.matrix` has a string input method, meant to imitate a MATLAB style:

```
In [1269]: alist =  ['12,-1', '0.01,3']
In [1270]: np.matrix(';'.join(alist))
Out[1270]: 
matrix([[  1.20000000e+01,  -1.00000000e+00],
        [  1.00000000e-02,   3.00000000e+00]])
In [1271]: _.A
Out[1271]: 
array([[  1.20000000e+01,  -1.00000000e+00],
       [  1.00000000e-02,   3.00000000e+00]])
```

It's a convenience.  I imagine the parsing involves something similar to what you do - several levels of split.

Doing our own split:

```
In [1273]: np.array([line.split(',') for line in alist])
Out[1273]: 
array([['12', '-1'],
       ['0.01', '3']],
      dtype='<U4')
```

If we specify the `dtype`, `np.array` will convert the strings to floats for us:

```
In [1274]: np.array([line.split(',') for line in alist],float)
Out[1274]: 
array([[  1.20000000e+01,  -1.00000000e+00],
       [  1.00000000e-02,   3.00000000e+00]])
```

The list comprehension creates a list of lists:

```
In [1275]: [line.split(',') for line in alist]
Out[1275]: [['12', '-1'], ['0.01', '3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [***numpy.split***](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) routine:

```
import numpy as np

list1 = ['12,-1', '0.01,3']
result = np.split(np.array([float(i) for _ in list1 for i in _.split(',')]), 2)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[array([ 12.,  -1.]), array([ 0.01,  3.  ])]
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be

```
import numpy as np

list1 = ['12,-1,2', '0.01,3,4','-2,3,4']
float_list = np.array([element for row in list1 for element in row.split(',')], dtype=np.float)
matrix = np.split(float_list, len(list1))
print(matrix)
```